# Load selective XML data into Dataset using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

Appreciate some pointers on how can I use XPath on XML file to extract only some data and load it into a dataset.

```
ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
```

will load the entire xml into dataset but my requirement is to load only particular node and values to dataset.

Sample xml data:

```
<data cobdate="5 Jul 2011" DBStatus="">
  <view>BOTH</view>
  <show_acctnbr>true</show_acctnbr>
  <summary>
    <headings sum="Summary" real_per="Realized this period" real_trd="Profit/loss in trading currency" real_select="Profit/loss in selected currency" short_term="Short Term Profit/Loss" long_term="Long Term Profit/Loss" />
    <account number="A123456" curr_code="USD" curr_desc="US Dollars" tradecurrvalue="123,123.00" selectcurrvalue="123,123.00" managed="NO" />
    <account number="P123456" curr_code="USD" curr_desc="US Dollars" tradecurrvalue="0.00" selectcurrvalue="0.00" managed="NO" />
  </summary>
  <detail>
    <headings dateaq="Date acquired" datesld="Date sold" desc="Description" sec_nbr="Security number " qty="Quantity" cost="Cost basis" />
    <account number="A123456" currency="US Dollars">
      <item datesold="29 Apr 11" sec_nbr="1234" description="SOME VALUE(USD)" quantity="8,000" proceeds="123,123.0" />
      <item datesold="29 Apr 11" sec_nbr="4567" description="SOME VALUE(USD)" quantity="9,000" proceeds="123,123.0" />
    </account>
    <account number="P123456" currency="US Dollars">
      <item datesold="29 Apr 11" sec_nbr="1234" description="SOME VALUE(USD)" quantity="8,000" proceeds="123,123.0" />
      <item datesold="29 Apr 11" sec_nbr="4567" description="SOME VALUE(USD)" quantity="9,000" proceeds="123,123.00" />
    </account>
  </detail>
</data>
```

In this example data, I just need to load accounts from `<summary>` node and if possible only number, tradecurrvalue and selectcurrvalue attributes. I using C# and 3.5.

Comment: Are XPath and DataSet requirements?

Comment: XPath is not a requirement.. but the requirement is to get the XML into a dataset. I just realized that my xml data is not in a file but will be passed to me as a string. I guess I can use `XDocument.Parse(string)`

Comment: Yes, Load or Parse doesn't matter.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression solution :)

Comment: @Dimitre that's not 1 line,  1 statement at best (:. And for comparison, add skeletal code to load the results into something else.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: This is a single XPath expression and it can be entered on a single line. I wouldn't start comparing the two solutions as they are very different in nature -- both have advantages and shortcomings.

Comment: @Dimitre Did you know that you can put _any_ C# program, no matter the size, on a single line?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: With Xpath 1.0 this is not exactly the same -- Not every desirable set of nodes can be selected with a single expression. Many people consider providing a single XPath 1.0 expression for "difficult cases" as an achievement. Thus the saying "XPath one-liner" -- it actually means "a single expression". In contrast one can implement any algorithm in a single C# program (file). Therefore, you are correct that "one-liner" is meaningless for C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var lst = doc
       .Descendants("summary")   // don't care where summary is
       .Elements("account ")     // direct child of <summary>
       .Select(x => new 
       {
          number = x.Attribute("number").Value,
          ...
       });

foreach(var account in lst) 
{
  .... // add to DataSet
}
```

Comment: Very neat solution Henk. Linq always amaze me the way it reduces the code lines. For now, I can work with this piece of code. Thanks!

Comment: @Henk if we know that there's just one summary node do we get any benefit if we use `doc.Element("summary")` instead of `doc.Decendants("summary")` particularly if the document is very large with lots of detail nodes after the summary?

Comment: #Conrad, You may get some benefit by specifying the exact path, at the loss of flexibility. But the major costs are loading and parsing, you already paid those.

Answer (score 2):

can also use **XmlNodeList** and **XmlNode**, light weight compared to others

```
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(node["Name"].InnerText.ToString(),
                            node["NoOfDay"].InnerText.ToString(),
                            node["dateColumn"].InnerText.ToString()
                           );
            }
```

[Reference Link](http://goo.gl/WjwAk0)

Answer (score 1):

**Evaluate this XPath expression in your code**:

```
/*/summary/account/@*
            [contains('|number|tradecurrvalue|selectcurrvalue|',
                      concat('|',name(),'|')
                      )
            ]
```

This selects any attribute (of any `account` element that is a child of any `summary` element that is a child of the top element in the XML document), named `"number"`, `"tradecurrvalue"` or `"selectcurrvalue"`

It is very easy to enlarge the list of possible attribute names you want selected -- just include them in the pipe-delimited name list.